# The use of format.pval in R (and with \Sexpr in Sweave)

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I have read the help file for `format.pval` and was wondering if this is a right tool to output numbers with proper format as far as significant digits are concerned

In this post:

[R / Sweave formatting numbers with \Sexpr{} in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366324/r-sweave-formatting-numbers-with-sexpr-in-scientific-notation)

a solution was proposed and I wonder if the function `format.pval` is already here to do this.

And I guess that we can just use it in Sweave as `\Sexpr{format.pval(a value/variable here)}` together with options for the number of significant digits.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: `format.pval` uses `format` which is more general in purpose.  So you should probably use `format`, `prettyNum` or `formatC` instead.

Comment: @ Andrie Thanks. Can you consider converting your comment in a a solution here? 1 vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format.pval` is specifically designed to format printed p.values, for example when viewing the output of `lm`.

The workhorse for `format.pval` is `format` which is more general in purpose. So you should probably use `format` or its cousins - `prettyNum` and `formatC` instead.

Footnote: for formatting dates (POSIXct or POSIXlt) you need the date formatting function `strptime`

Answer (score 3):

I have included that functionality in the `knitr` package, which makes `knitr` really smart now -- it automatically uses `$a \times 10^b$` if your `\Sexpr{}` produces a number and it is either too big or too small (if you output HTML instead of TeX, it automatically uses `a &times; 10<sup>b</sup>`). You can probably start switching from Sweave to `knitr` now: http://yihui.github.com/knitr/

Comment: Thanks. Is knitr stable? I understand that it is much more recent than Sweave, 1 vote up.

Comment: The first version will be released to CRAN very soon, and it can be considered as stable then.

Answer (score 1):

I think `format.pval` should probably not be used. We (statisticians) generally don't use conventional scientific notation for $p$-values because the leading 0s are also a reflection of precision. Thus we use total digits. You will find this in most scholarly publications.

For instance, reporting three digits means "trace" values are reported with "<0.001" as in the greatest precision afforded is to the thousands-th place. If I specify `digits=3` and `eps=0.001`, a p-value of 0.0040523 is reported as 0.00405 suggesting my precision is to the hundred-thousandsth place when 0.004 would have been desired.

I use the following little wrapper:

```
format.p <- function(p, precision=0.001) {
  digits <- -log(precision, base=10)
  p <- formatC(p, format='f', digits=digits)
  p[p == formatC(0, format='f', digits=digits)] <- paste0('<', precision)
  p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be conservative, a p-value of 0.32312 should be rounded to 0.324, not 0.323. Here's my solution:

```
format.p = function(p, precision=0.001) {
  digits = -log(precision, base=10)
  p = formatC(ceiling(p/precision)*precision,format = 'f', digits=digits)
  p[p == formatC(0, format='f', digits=digits)] = paste0('<', precision)
  p
}
```