# How to avoid using round() in every \Sexpr{}?

Tags: r, latex, sweave, knitr

Is there a way to avoid the function `round()`  when using Sweave/knitr? It's really annoying to write `round(,2)` in every `\Sexpr{}`. I would like to have two decimal places through the whole document.

Thanks for your help
Macs

Comment: IMHO you could set a [hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks) for that. Or try [pander](http://daroczig.github.com/pander/) which does that automatically :)

Comment: Do you want to limit the output to two digits max, or do you always want two digits, even if they are zero (`1.00`)? The first you should be able to achieve with setting `options( digits = 2 )` in your first chunk.

Comment: @vaettchen: setting `digits` to `2`, you would get `pi*100` as `314` which is a quite rough estimate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programming R/Sweave for proper \Sexpr output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486130/programming-r-sweave-for-proper-sexpr-output)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you have read [the motivation](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#motivation) of the [`knitr` package](http://yihui.name/knitr/), you probably know I'm the person who hates `round()` inside `\Sexpr{}` most. I suggested this to R core long time ago for Sweave but it was ignored, so I started my own package.

Although the answer by Josh O'Brien is absolutely correct, I should say you really only need `options(digits = 2)` with `knitr`, and there is no need to reset the default inline hook because the default hook respects this option.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. It's really a great relief. I'm quite a beginner in the work with R and LaTeX, but nevertheless the advantages over Sweave are fairly obvious. I think in a short time most people will have changed to knitr.

Answer (score 15):

In `knitr`, the **inline** hook can be used to process the output of `\Sexpr{}` statements. So, if you want to print just 2 digits after the decimal for inline code (while leaving the overall `digits` option alone) you can do so like this:

```
## First have a look at the default inline hook function
knit_hooks$get("inline")

## Then customize it to your own liking
inline_hook <- function(x) {
    if(is.numeric(x)) x <- round(x, 2)
    paste(as.character(x), collapse=", ")
}
knit_hooks$set(inline = inline_hook)
```

Comment: +1 - neat, as this adds the abbility to distinguish between inline and chunk appearance !

Comment: @PeterM -- Absolutely! [See baptiste's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405536/knitr-inline-chunk-options-no-evaluation-or-just-render-highlighted-code) for another (very useful) example of a customized inline hook.

Answer (score 6):

First, you perhaps want to use `formatC` instead of `round` to get two digits even when they are zero.  There's not a great way to do this in Sweave; the best option is probably simply to make a new function with a short name that does the formatting you want; something like

```
p <- function(x) {formatC(x, format="f", digits=2)}
```

That at least saves a little bit of typing:

```
The answer is $\Sexpr{p(x)}$.
```

Unfortunately, without mucking about with a new Sweave driver, I don't think there's anything else to do (perhaps this is another reason to try `knitr`, which seems to be gaining ground fast).  Sweave is doing this on what's inside your `Sexpr` statement, and then replacing the `Sexpr` call with the result.

```
as.character(eval(parse(text = cmd), envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

However, you can't just write a new version of `as.character`; aside from the issue that it might change behavior in other unexpected ways, because of the namespacing, it always calls the version in `base` even if there's another version in the global environment.

Comment: It is so natural to think of dark voodoos with Sweave :) You know exactly where Sweave should change, and this is also what I suggested to R core (they can do better not only using `as.character`) and ignored by them.

Comment: Yes, dark voodoos indeed.  I have a couple variant drivers sitting around that add certain functionality I need but they're a pain to write and maintain.  I keep hearing good things about `knitr` and how it makes a lot of things easier.  Hope to try it soon.  Thanks for your work on it, @Yihui.