# pander number of digits after decimal point

Tags: r, r-markdown, pander

I am trying to output a table using pander in a .rmd file as a pdf with 2 digits following the decimal point, but I get no digits using the following rmd:

````
---
title: "Long table test"
output: pdf_document
---

Here is a table:

```{r setup}
library (data.table)
library (pander)

set.seed(1984)
longString <- "description string"
dt <- data.table(id=c(1:3),description=rep(longString,3),value=rnorm(3,mean=10000,sd=1))
```

```{r pander-table}
panderOptions('round',2)
panderOptions('digits',2)
panderOptions('keep.trailing.zeros',TRUE)
pander(dt, split.cell = 80, split.table = Inf)
```
````

results in

```
-------------------------------
 id     description      value 
---- ------------------ -------
 1   description string  10000 

 2   description string  10000 

 3   description string  10001 
-------------------------------
```

Would like to see

```
----------------------------------
 id     description      value 
---- ------------------ ----------
 1   description string  10000.41 

 2   description string   9999.68 

 3   description string  10000.64 
----------------------------------
```

Comment: My first change would be to drop the digits option. If it's linked to the signif function in R it would have the effect you are seeing: `signif( mean(rnorm(1000,1000)), 2)` returns `[1] 1000`. And `signif( mean(rnorm(10,1000, 200)), 2)` returns `[1] 990`

Comment: Increase `digits` to 7.

Comment: Setting digits to 7 will give me `9999.677` (i.e. 3 digits after decimal place) or `10000.64`. If I set digits to 7 and round to 2 `panderOptions('digits',7); panderOptions('round',2)` then I get the desired result. Seems like more of a work around than a general solution since it cannot be applied consistently to all data, I need to know how many digits I will have in my data and adjust appropriately. It would be nice if pander behaved in a similar way to `kable(x, digits=2)` which results in 2 digits after the decimal.

Comment: @DavidDickson `knitr::kable` passes `digits` to `round` -- what you can achieve in `pander` as well by setting `round` to `2`, I think this is pretty sane and provides great flexibility. What's wrong with setting a large `digits` and `round` to `2`?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `round` doesn't have any direct influence on the number of digits (though some indirect influence due to potentially rendering digits insignificant (`0`)). The main problem here is pander doesn't allow you to set the `nsmall` parameter of `format()` which would set

> the minimum number of digits to the right of the decimal point in formatting real/complex numbers in non-scientific formats. Allowed values are 0 <= nsmall <= 20.

But since pander only feeds numeric values to `format()` you can simply work around this by feeding the values `as.character()` to pander:

```r
library (data.table)
library(magrittr)
library (pander)

set.seed(1984)
longString <- "description string"
dt <- data.table(id = c(1:3),
                 description = rep(longString, 3),
                 value = rnorm(3, mean = 10000, sd = 1))

pander(
  x = dt %>% mutate(value = value %>% round(2) %>% as.character()),
  split.cell = 80,
  split.table = Inf,
  justify = "ccr"
)
```

which results in:

```
------------------------------------
 id      description           value
---- -------------------- ----------
 1    description string    10000.41

 2    description string     9999.68

 3    description string    10000.64
------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`?panderOptions`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pander/versions/0.6.3/topics/panderOptions) page notes that 'digits' is passed to `format` where it is interpreted as the number of "significant digits". Significant digits really have very little to do with decimal places. You can have 2 significant digits in a decimal value of 0.000041. You can see the effect of your parameter on your `format()`-ed values:

```
> format(c( 10000.41,  9999.68, 10000.64 ), digits=2)
[1] "10000" "10000" "10001"
```

You do want to keep the "round" option at 2.

Comment: removing the `panderOptions('digits',2)` and keeping `panderOptions('round',2)` produced the exact same result.

Comment: Maybe the digits setting is "durable"? Did you try setting it to NA or 7?

Comment: @42- setting `digits` to `7` will achieve the desired results, see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `digits` part. You have to increase the number to the maximum digits before and after the decimal point. Your biggest numbers (concerning digits) have 5 digits before and 2 after the decimal (e.g. 10000.41). So you need to set digits to 7 and (leave) round at 2:

````
```{r pander-table}
panderOptions('round',2)
panderOptions('digits',7)
panderOptions('keep.trailing.zeros',TRUE)
pander(dt, split.cell = 80, split.table = Inf)
```
````